# SwiftUI Picker item .foregroundColor() not working

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to set the color of the text within a Picker but it is not actually changing anything. The following is my code:

```
Picker("Theme Color", selection: $themeColor) {
    ForEach(0..<themeColors.count) { _ in
        Text("Color").foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
}.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

Is this just not possible in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 5):

Well... nothing direct, but you can play with the following approach... which allows to get some interesting effects (maybe someone could be appropriate)

Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo1]

```
    Picker("Theme Color", selection: $themeColor) {
         ForEach(0..<4) { _ in
              Text("Color")
         }
    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    .colorMultiply(.white).colorInvert()
```

and even

[image: demo2]

```
    Picker("Theme Color", selection: $themeColor) {
         ForEach(0..<4) { _ in
              Text("Color")
         }
    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    .colorMultiply(.white).colorInvert()
    .colorMultiply(.orange).colorInvert()
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to `change` the foreground color of the picker, but it was far from good since the chosen item would not be readable.
Considering my iOS 13 unfortunate experiences with segmented picker, and the fact that i couldn't change the picker's size at that time, i do think that pickers are still not customizable and just like me, you'll need to write your own picker if you want a more customized one.

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI 2, `Picker` is still backed by `UISegmentedControl`.

Which means you can use the `UISegmentedControl.appearance()` modifiers:

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = .systemOrange
UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .systemRed
```

Comment: This is getting me close but is there a way to change each one individually?

Comment: @JoeScotto You may set the background color individually but I'm not aware of the solution for the selected item (you can always try Asperi's solution).

Comment: How would you do it for each item? The selected one I would just like a border or something.

Comment: @JoeScotto You can do `UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear` and then just apply the `background(Color.red)` modifier to your picker. But I don't know the way to access the appearance of the selected segment in SwiftUI.

Comment: @JoeScotto Did you find a solution to change the rows colors individually?

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired results using "setTitleTextAttributes"

```swift
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .normal)
```

I added this line in the init() method of the parent view.

```swift
public init() {
      UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor(colorManager.p3)], for: .normal)
}
```

Notice that you need a UIColor, not SwiftUI's Color